# Is there a way to change the rate at which a cURL SSL session ID becomes stale?

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I have a set of PHP scripts running on a low-powered embedded device which use the cURL PHP library to POST data every second to a remote server. The cURL transfer is secure, but the slowdown to calculate the handshake for each connection was untenable. I changed it to make use of cURL's connection caching, and now only the initial connection takes a long time. However, every two hundred connections or so, about once every five minutes, I get the following messages:

```
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
```

Then the SSL handshake happens again, causing a noticeable delay in the data, and subsequent connections work quickly for another five minutes.

I understand the need to refresh the connection, but on such a slow CPU, and with such high granularity, I would like to make the refreshes less frequent. I haven't had any success with search engines. Does anyone know what enforces this refresh, and whether there is a frequency variable I can change?

The remote server is under my control. It uses Apache and OpenSSL to provide secure connections.

Comment: Do you own the remote server? If yes you may want to set the session timeout to be a rolling instance. Meaning the expiry time instead of being 5 minutes would be 5 minutes from last access.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that I'm using Apache and OpenSSL. If you want to post an answer saying that I need to change the session timeout, I would be happy to accept that as it was the phrase I needed to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Apache and OpenSSL, you may want to change the SSLSessionCacheTimeout value to 15 minutes or more (in seconds) depending upon requirement.

UPDATE: [More Info](http://www.apacheref.com/ref/mod_ssl/SSLSessionCacheTimeout.html)

Comment: That solves the problem of constant delays, but having a rolling instance where expiry only happens after not connecting for a while sounds good. Can you point me in the direction of some resources on that?

Comment: More Info Link expires. SSLSessionCacheTimeout changed to 900 but the same error occurs. Any suggestions pls.